# How can I read a document with pandas (python) that don't look like the average one?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the values from the colums from a file. The doc looks like this
[the data I want to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExdNa.png)

So all the examples I have found uses pd.read_csv or pd.DataFrame but all data usually have a clear header an nothing on top of the data (I have like 10 lines of code I don't really need for what I am doing).

Also, I think maybe there is something wrong because I tried to run:

data = pd.read_csv('tdump_BIL_100_-96_17010100.txt',header=15)

and I get

[pd.read_csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x5ry.png)

which is just the row in one column, so there is no separation apparently, and therefore no way of getting the columns I need.

So my question is if there is a way to get the data from this file with pandas and how to get it.

Comment: Try to use `header=None, skiprows=15, sep='\s+'` when executing `read_csv`. By the way, you should not insert pictures of your input and output: it is preferred to copy-paste portions of your input and output, so people could try to run some code on your input. If I were able to copy-paste your input, I would try to read that data with `read_csv` and tell you precisely what to do.

Comment: Your data does not look like a table, it looks more like many tables (with different columns) stacked on top of each other? What is exactly the output you desire? For custom file formats (like yours) I think you should look into writing your own parser.

Answer (score 1):

If a defined number, skip the initial rows, indicate that no header is present, and that values are separated by spaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=15, header=None, sep='\s+')
```

See [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for documentation.